# rsyslog server generating log files named for IP address instead of access_log

Tags: rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have a syslog-ng server configured to send all apache log messages to a remote rsyslog server.  Here are the pertinent part of my syslog-ng server's config:

```
source s_http {
    file("/var/log/httpd/access_log" flags(no-parse));
};

...

destination loghost { tcp("10.0.0.48" port(514)); }; 

...

log { source(s_http); destination(loghost); };
```

I was hoping to find on the remote rsyslog server (10.0.0.48) the file: `/apps/log/my-web-server/access_log`. but instead I find several files in the `/apps/log/my-web-server/` named for the IP address of the clients that hit `my-web-server` with a .log extension.

```
[root@10.0.0.48]# pwd
/apps/log/my-web-server
[root@10.0.0.48]# ls -l
total 140
-rw-------. 1 root root   4862 Aug 14 16:39 10.0.0.97.log
-rw-------. 1 root root    193 Aug 14 15:45 10.0.0.201.log
```

Why aren't the log messages going into one file named `access_log`?

Update:

On the rsyslog server at 10.0.0.48 I see these lines in the /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
$template RemoteStore, "/apps/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
$template RemoteStoreFormat, "%msg%\n"
:source, !isequal, "localhost" -?RemoteStore;RemoteStoreFormat
:source, isequal, "last" STOP
```

what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change ...

```
source s_http {
    file("/var/log/httpd/access_log" flags(no-parse));
};
```

... to this ...

```
source s_http {
    file("/var/log/httpd/access_log" program-override("apache_access_log"));
};
```